# My docker postgres is persisting data even between stopping the container and deleting all volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

This is a bit of an odd question: There are a ton of articles on how to persist docker data between sessions but I DO NOT want the docker data to be persisted between sessions, yet postgres tables and rows seem to be preserved between taking down the docker image and starting it.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD notasecret
ENV POSTGRES_USER my_app
ENV POSTGRES_DB my_app_test

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gzip

COPY . .

ADD init.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The init.sql.gz added at the bottom of the file are my integration test fixtures that I want the database to be loaded with at the start of the test run.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_app_test_postgres:
    build: .
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "7432:5432"
```

Ok, heres what I see. This docker image is intended to be used as a postgres instance for integration testing. At the start of the test, the database should contain exactly and only the initialization data contained in init.sql.gz.

When I run docker-compose up, the database starts as expected. But when I stop the instance and restart it, I see that changes from the test are persisted. In fact, the changes continue to persist even if I delete the docker image and remove the volume!

Here's how I'm resetting the database between test runs:

```sh
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker-compose up
```

If I understand properly, these commands should delete both all docker containers and all attached volumes. Yet when I restart the container, the changes are still there.

Another oddity - I've tried replacing init.sql.gz with a different init.sql.gz to see if schema changes are picked up when I rebuild the image. As it turns out, replacing the init.sql.gz has no effect whatsoever! Even if I completely exclude it from the image, I keep getting the database tables from the previous test run.

I've discovered that if I completely nuke the docker cache, and delete ALL cached images, then rebuild from scratch, that seems to solve the issue - but I don't want to do that every time.

What's the right way to tell docker, "Start this container from scratch, and delete all persistent data"? I am mystified as to how the data is being persisted, as I am deleting the volumes between test runs!

Comment: On every restart you create the new image with `ADD init.sql.gz` data, it is not the persistent data, it is coming from your init.

Comment: I understand that. But if I replace the init.sql.gz with a completely different schema, I don't get the new schema - I get the one from the original init.sql.gz.

Comment: `docker rmi <IMAGE_ID>`, you are building the image build you are not removing the image.